# Find something that does not match a pattern at the beginning of line

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex in Python to find something at the beginning of line that does not match pattern "SCENE" and before colon. The text looks like this

```
SCENE:xxxxxxdd\nAQW:xxxxxdd\nSCENE:xxxxxdf\nCER:dddd.ddd\nddd\nDYU:ddddd\nddd\nd\nEOI:ddd\n.
```

I need to find AQW, CER, DYU, EOI in this case.

I have tried

```
findall(r"^(?!SCENE)[^:]*, text, re.M)
```

I get AQW and EOI, but I get `ddd\nDYU` instead of DYU, `ddd\nd\nEOI` instead of EOI.

How could I get exactly AQW,CER,DYU,EOI?

Comment: Does the text span multiple lines, or is it one line and literally has `\n` typed into it?

Comment: To confirm, you're looking for only a single uppercase letter at the beginning of the line and before a colon?

Comment: Try `^[a-z]*(?!B)([A-Z])` See https://regex101.com/r/lTely1/1

Comment: It's not single uppercase letter. It's a word. Let me rewrite my question.

Comment: @StevenHsu in that case does `^(?!SCENE)[A-Z]+(?=:)` work for you?

Comment: @ctwheels No it returns an empty list.

Comment: Did you enable multiline using `^`? Try using `(?<!\S)(?!SCENE)[A-Z]+` See https://regex101.com/r/aZyIcQ/1 or `\b(?!SCENE)[A-Z]+` https://regex101.com/r/PJora2/1

Comment: I enabled multiline findall(r"^(?!SCENE)[^:]*, text, re.M). It works better, but I get AQW and EOI, but I get ddd\nDYU instead of DYU, ddd\nd\nEOI instead of EOI.

Comment: @StevenHsu That is because the negated character class `[^:]` also matches a newline. It could be `^(?!SCENE)[^:\r\n]*` but that will match more than only uppercase chars.

Comment: @Thefourthbird if it is known that only uppercase letters have to be matched, `re.findall(r'^(?!SCENE)[A-Z]+(?=:)', text, flags=re.M)` should do right?

Comment: @Sundeep That will work, it was suggested by ctwheels as well but the OP replied `No it returns an empty list`

Comment: @Thefourthbird that was probably tried before `re.M` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
findall (r"\n(?!SCENE)(.+?):")
```

which works. The point is I did not realize that I can use parenthesis to select what I would like to display in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to brteak your string to substrings and try to find there:

```
import re
line = "SCENE:xxxxxxdd\nAQW:xxxxxdd\nSCENE:xxxxxdf\nCER:dddd.ddd\nddd\nDYU:ddddd\nddd\nd\nEOI:ddd\n."
lines = re.split("\\n([A-Z])", line)
lines = [a+b for a,b in zip(lines[1::2], lines[2::2])]
for line in lines:
    if re.match(r"^(?!SCENE)[^:]*", line):
        print(line.split(":")[0])
```

result is:

```
AQW
CER
DYU
EOI
```

This answer is not the best in terms of performance I assume

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be simplified more, and I'm assuming that `\n` in your example string is a literal newline character.

This should match all of your use cases. It starts by looking for any number of characters that aren't `SCENE` preceding a `:` then it finds any characters after the colon that don't follow a newline and precede a `:` then the last `.` there is probably a way around, but the final character wasn't being properly matched because it was directly followed by the negative lookahead.

```py
findall( r"([A-Z]+(?<!SCENE):(?:[\s\S](?!\n[A-Z]+:))+.)", text )
```

https://regex101.com/r/NwdUcR/2

EDIT: I realize the above may not be exactly what you're looking for. If you're looking to match just the letters before the colon you can use this:

```py
findall( r"([A-Z]+(?<!SCENE)):", text )
```

Comment: Right it works if I am looking for uppercase letters before the colon. I did not make it clear that it could be anything before the colon. I use findall(r"\n(?!SCENE)(.+?):"), which works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex in this case.
Here is a solution using plain and simple `str.split()`.

```
s = 'SCENE:xxxxxxdd\nAQW:xxxxxdd\nSCENE:xxxxxdf\nCER:dddd.ddd\nddd\nDYU:ddddd\nddd\nd\nEOI:ddd\n.'
matches = [m.split('\n')[-1] for m in s.split(':') if 'SCENE' not in m]
>>> matches
['AQW', 'CER', 'DYU', 'EOI', '.']
```

If you want to exclude the last `'.'`, you can use `matches = [m.split('\n')[-1] for m in s.split(':') if (('SCENE' not in m) and (m[-1] != '.'))]`
 or simply `matches = matches[:-1]`